Order in dockerfile: will this throw error
RUN echo $MY_VARIABLE
ENV MY_VARIABLE="some value"




instead should i write like
ENV MY_VARIABLE="some value"
RUN echo $MY_VARIABLE

i want to know does order matter in dockerfile if i write run  command first then put the ENV will it throw an error

There doesn't seem to be any difference between your code blocks. Also that's something you can find out very easily.

According to Dockerfile reference. Docker runs instructions in a Dockerfile in order.

Yes , I believe the order does matter. You should first declare the variable and set it.
